# AngularJS filter removing child elements

Tags: angularjs, filter, tree

I'm working on an angular-tree object which is filtering pretty well. but when the search string matches only on a parent element, none of a child elements can be seen and the expand functionality is also disappearing from the filtered node.

Is there any way to write a custom filter that won't eliminate the child elements (subnodes and leafs) if the search only matches on parent element?

Taking this page as an example:

```
http://ee.github.io/angular-ui-tree-filter/
```

When you search for: 'tofu-animation', the tree-control closes the node 2.1 and not showing their child elements, because no exact match on them, but how can I leave the 2.1 node open?

Let's take a good example. That's what I need in angular tree-control:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/slemmon/fSJwF/2/
```

If you search for 'algebra' it can be found under 'homework' parent, that's fine, this is the standard angular-tree filtering.
But, if you search for 'homework', it shows the parent 'homework' node and their child elements and 'do homework' leaf element in 'chores' parent.

Thx,
Tibor

Comment: Can you please add your code to see what you're having? A jsfiddle would be great.

Comment: The code in http://ee.github.io/angular-ui-tree-filter/ only greys out the children. You don't want this to happen?

Comment: I can't put my code on fiddle because it's on my company's pc. What I can't do with angular tree filter is leaving the child element(s) expandable, clickable if the searchterm matches only on parent element. Angular-tree base filter is hiding all the child elements when parent matches only.

I can't explain clearer that my second example (searching for homework) in my original question.

Comment: I need exactly this with angular-tree-object:

http://jsfiddle.net/slemmon/fSJwF/2/